# Height of a div with absolutely positioned children

Tags: html, css

I have a bunch of html that is absolutely positioned and then html snippet that is supposed to show after that. But they over lap.

http://jsbin.com/okamot/1/edit

Everything under `.drag-drop` is supposed to be absolutely placed so the height and width of `.drag-drop` become zero. The exhibit button and the exhibit text are supposed to show after the bolded `This is Drag and Drop Item`. But because the height of `.drag-drop` is zero it shows right over the contents of .drag-drop`.

I have had this issue before, but fortunately it was easy to calculate the height of the children of `.drag-drop` and then I would set the height of the `.drag-drop` to be that using javascript. This time it is harder as it contains more children and they are not constant. How would I change my css so that the Exhibit shows below the drag drop ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Absolute positioning removes the element from the layout, therefore the children are no longer part of the calculation of the parent's sizing. You'll need to use JS to solve this.

Comment: Ok, thanks for the reply, could you point me in a direction ?

Comment: I would suggest looking at an existing drag/drop script, such as jQuery UI.

Comment: For my situation, this is the best answer, so I am marking this correct.

Answer (score 1):

The best way is not to make the content absolute positioned at all. Could you make them relative positioned, or float them? You can still manipulate their position, height, width, etc., and they'd have layout so the containing div would have the correct height.

Note if you float them, you may need to add a "float breaker" at the bottom of the containing div to get it to calculate the height correctly:
`....
   <div>some floated content</div>
   <br style="float: none;"/> // float-breaker right before containing div closes
</div>`

Otherwise the previous answerer is correct, you'll need some js hackery.

Comment: The right answer IMO, but I would recommend a clearfix class, and not a clearing br. You should try to never change your content just for styling.

Comment: Thanks for the reply murdoch, but the setup is weird. There is no way around the absolute positioning. These are coordinates saved on the server-side, that are sent to UI and the expectation is to render things accordingly. IMO there is no other way than to use javascript to change the height of `.drag-drop` so that the rest of the page looks nice.

Comment: Eesh, tough break. Hope you find a reasonably elegant way to hack that. FWIW PeterVR is right, should you find yourself in that situation.